# d3 svg rect does not render in chrome

Tags: google-chrome, d3.js, svg

i made a bar chart with the d3 library (mostly working and testing in firefox) and later noticed the `fill` attributes for `svg rect` in chrome weren't rendering, thus only displaying the `x` and `y` axes.

the same thing happens in safari iOS *(i can't test as vigorously but checked to see if it was exclusively happening in chrome)*.

does anyone know why this is?
a hint in the right direction would still be appreciated;
i'm at a wall.

here's a [pen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/aRdMMz).

to clarify:
the `svg rect` in firefox is rendered as intended.

if it's a bug, here's the [version of each browser i'm running](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qVv1o.png) at the current time

Comment: the problem is your `*` CSS selector. There is no need to use `*` and it is somehow discouraged also regarding speed. If you change `*` to `html` you see the bars. Why do you set the fill of the rect and in the CSS `.bar`, Just noticed it is commented in CSS

Comment: why don't you use `d3.json`?

Comment: @rioV8 my guy, thank you; i wasn't aware it was bad practice. this fixes my problem. i might delete this question, considering it boiled down to bad css, unless you want free internet points.  

i mainly tried following d3 documentation; are you saying i shouldn't use the d3 cdn and instead use a local json file?

Comment: there is no need to write your own `XMLHttpRequest`, use `d3.json` that uses the Fetch API with Promises

Comment: @rioV8 nifty. will try to figure out. thanks for the pointers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your * selector contains

```
width: auto;
height: auto;
```

Somehow this is overriding the width and height of the rect elements even though it shouldn't as the rect elements have width and height attributes. Remove those settings and things display correctly.

Comment: precisely those two properties caused the problem; thank you for looking into it.